# Need help creating a session from database values

Tags: php, variables, session

(Note: have looked at similar questions relating to this but those haven't worked for me in my case)

So the code below is the php for when the user logs in with their username and password. The website has an online currency system. So when they log in I want to try and grab the amount of 'money' that that user has and then turn it into a Session variable so I can use it elsewhere to echo the value.

In this code it creates a session based on the value in the login box. But I want to create a session out of their current 'token' value.

([Image of Phpmyadmin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SovoN.png))

^ So if I'm trying to log into my acc "Nanikos" I want to get the value of my Tokens from the token column, in this case it's 1000. And then turn that into a session so I can echo that 1000 around the website.

Just not sure how to go about that since I've never tried doing this before aha.

```
<?php

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "czt_Nanikos";
$password = "CZTCb030499";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Select Database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "czt_database");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//Error handlers
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    } else {    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //De-hashing the password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //Log in the user
                    $_SESSION["UID"] = $uid;
                    header("Location: ../index.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
{
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: is `$_SESSION["UID"]` not working? what was the issue?

Comment: You should use prepared statements and throw out those escape strings.    Beyond that, you may want to show where you're using the session data.  Are you including session_start() there as well?

Comment: User's token balance is not something you should be storing in the session in my opinion. Either way you need to update the database when you add/remove tokens, so you might as well just use only the database.

Answer (score 0):

On this page, modify the part where you login the user:

```
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing the password
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                //Log in the user
                $_SESSION["UID"] = $uid;

                /**
                 * Add the line below ...............::
                 **/
                $_SESSION['token'] = $row['tokens'];

                header("Location: ../index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
```

On your next page, do:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (array_key_exists('token', $_SESSION) {
        $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    } else {
        //redirect to login page
    }

    /* continue code for page */
```